# Setting set sql_mode value on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds

We have recently migrated our databases to AWS RDS.

We would like to set **sql_mode** value as **null**, (SET sql_mode = "";) in AWS RDS, but when we checked in the RDS parameter groups we couldn't find a value equal for **null**. We are using MariaDB 10.2.12 on RDS.

Can anyone please help on this??

Comment: Fortunately we got the answer:

Comment: We got it resolved by enabling sql_mode parameter on RDS as NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the value to 0.

The Allowed values for sql_mode (on a mysql8 instance) include:

> 0, ANSI, ALLOW_INVALID_DATES, ANSI_QUOTES, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,
> HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE, IGNORE_SPACE, NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,
> NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES, NO_DIR_IN_CREATE, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,
> NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION, NO_ZERO_DATE, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,
> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH, PIPES_AS_CONCAT,
> REAL_AS_FLOAT, STRICT_ALL_TABLES, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, TRADITIONAL,
> TIME_TRUNCATE_FRACTIONAL

You can apply these as a list, for example the following matches the mysql8 default:

> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_ALL_TABLES